# Windows batch file to remove files from directories but retain latest file in each directory

Tags: batch-file, perforce

I'm trying to write a windows script (for Win7/Server 2008) that removes files older than a certain date while retaining the most recent file regardless of age.

Perforce stores versioned binary files on a server or proxy by encapsulating it in a directory.

For example, if I store image.jpg on the server and update it twice, it will store it in a directory like "image.jpg,d" with numbered gzip files inside.

e.g.

```
c:\depot\1\image.jpg,d\123.gz | last modified: 9/1/2013
c:\depot\1\image.jpg,d\124.gz | last modified: 10/1/2013
c:\depot\1\image.jpg,d\125.gz | last modified: 11/1/2013
c:\depot\2\image.jpg,d\123.gz | last modified: 9/1/2013
c:\depot\2\image.jpg,d\124.gz | last modified: 10/1/2013
c:\depot\2\image.jpg,d\125.gz | last modified: 11/1/2013
```

In this case, if I ran the standard forfiles removal script for files older than 14 days, all six files would be removed. Am looking for a solution where in this scenario, 123.gz and 124.gz are removed, but 125.gz is left alone in both directories.

If there is a single file in a folder like this:

```
c:\depot\1\hw\images\helloworld.jpg,d\122.gz | last modified 1/1/2013
```

It will leave the file alone. If there are multiple, it will leave the most recent one.

This solution is similar but was unsuccessful with Win7: [How to use forfiles (or similar) to delete files older than n days, but always leaving most recent n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691266/how-to-use-forfiles-or-similar-to-delete-files-older-than-n-days-but-always-l)

Answer (score 0):

Change `"c:\server\folder"` to the base location and run this:

The code is designed to leave the most recent modified file in each folder, and delete the rest.

It will merely echo the del commands to the screen so change `echo del` to `del` and run it again to make it function if it's doing what you want.

```
@echo off
for /d /r "c:\server\folder" %%a in (*) do (
   pushd "%%a" && (
      echo processing "%%a"
         for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%b in ('dir /b /a-d /o-d') do echo del "%%b"
   popd
   )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions

    set "_depot=c:\depot"

    rem Enumerate all the directories under depot, 
    rem and retrieve only those that end with ,d
    for /f "tokens=*" %%d in ('cmd /q /c "(for /r "%_depot%" %%a in (.) do echo "%%~fa")" ^| findstr /e ",d"""') do (
        rem list the files in selected directory, ordered by creation date descending
        rem skip the first file in list and delete the rest
        for /f "tokens=* skip=1" %%f in ('dir /a-d /tc /o-d /b "%%d\*.gz" 2^>nul') do (
            rem WARNING !!! 
            rem DELETING FILES. Remove echo when sure it works as needed
            rem WARNING !!!
            echo del "%%~fd\%%f" 
        )
    )
    endlocal
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a recent enough version of the Perforce server, the 'p4 archive' command will do the file archive removal for you.

Here's the docs: http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/p4_archive.html